# Enviar una constante junto con un array a la base de datos con laravel

Tags: laravel, array, base-de-datos, laravel-6

primero que nada quiero disculparme si mi pregunta esta algo mal formulada, soy nuevo aquí.

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de insertar user_id y questionnaire_id a mi base de datos de esta forma:

```
 $iduser=  auth()->user()->id;
  $questionnaire_id=$request['questionnaire_id'];
        DB::table('resultquestionnaires')->insert([
            'user_id' => $iduser,
            'questionnaire_id' => $questionnaire_id,
        ]);
```

Ahora en el siguiente código estoy recorriendo un array con questions_id y correctoption_id para  registrar varios registros, en mi caso estoy realizando un módulo de cuestionarios y estoy intentando almacenar los resultados de dicho cuestionario

```
`if (count($request->question_id) > 0)
{

    foreach ($request->question_id as $item=>$v)
    {
        $data=array
        (
            'question_id'=>$request->question_id[$item],
            'correctoption_id'=>$request->correctoption_id[$item],
        );
            ResultQuestionnaire::insert($data);

    }`
```

Pero como es de lógica, el controlador insertara primero id_user,id_questionnaire y no tendrá en cuenta el foreach que recorre el array, ese es mi problema como logro insertar id_user y id_questionnaire junto con el array $data, ya pobre colocandolos dentro del array, pero como estos valores no son array  el foreach no los podra iterar

Agradezco de antemano sus consejos soy nuevo en laravel, y disculpen si tal vez no me hago entender bien

**Nota Solucionado**
lo logre resolver de la siguiente forma

```
  foreach ($request->question_id as $item=>$v)
    {
        $data=array
        (
            'questionnaire_id'=>$request['questionnaire_id'],
            'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id,
            'question_id'=>$request->question_id[$item],
            'correctoption_id'=>$request->correctoption_id[$item],
            'created_at'=>Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at'=>Carbon::now(),
        );
            ResultQuestionnaire::insert($data);
    }
```

había intentado esto antes, pero no me fije en que questionnaire_id, lo estaba enviando como un array cuando este no lo es, ahora lo mando normal desde la vista a través de un input oculto

Comment: El user_id lo tomas del usuario actualmente autenticado?

Comment: si señor.......